# JQuery - CSS ninja help wanted

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer, jquery-ui, slider

I'm using the JQuery Slider Control

IE 6 looks FUBAR.

Screenshot (how it should look)
img24.imageshack.us/img24/9786/safarij.png

Screenshot (IE6)
img99.imageshack.us/img99/3418/ie6o.png

What CSS can I use for IE6 to make it look like Firefox/Chrome/Safari?

Any CSS ninja magic would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding font-size: 0; that's helped me in situations like this in the past.

Or maybe zoom: 1; to get IE to tag the element has having hasLayout.

**Update on this:**

Just tested by adding

```
 div.ui-slider-range
,div.ui-widget-header
{
    font-size: 0;
}
```

and it seemed to work, zoom:1 wasn't needed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the line-height of the blue bar element, and set a height too. Set those attributes with _ before them (like _height: 2px) so that only IE will parse them.

If you care about CSS validation, then do what Daniel White suggested.

Comment: @changelog, it appears the 2 DIV of importance are:    .ui-slider-range  & .ui-slider-horizontal. I've added the following CSS to those DIV and it still doesn't help.  "height: 2px; _height: 2px; line-height: 2px"

Answer (score 0):

To achieve the curved 'buttons' on the slider, the script uses CSS property border-radius, which is not supported in <=ie6. The blue bar is easy enough to fix, just give it a fixed height and a line height.

Answer (score -2):

Use IE's conditional comments to craft a special stylesheet that is specific for IE6 to fix any problems.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537512%28VS.85%29.aspx

Comment: What I'm saying is that I cannot figure out what's causing IE 6 to display such a large height. Meaning, I don't know what CSS I need to use, even if it was conditional, to make IE display the correct blue bar height

Comment: @Daniel A White, I have been experiment actually. I'm not the best at CSS. I'm tried a ton of different things and none seem to work. Which is why I posted this question. Any help would be GREATLY appreciated